# Gulp Error: Cannot find module browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

Getting the above error when running gulp.

Can't figure out why. I've read a few things such as the gulp.src needs a ./ infront of app.

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {

gulp.src(['./app/main.js'])
    .pipe(browserify({
        debug: true,
        transform: [ 'reactify' ]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

Like so..

I've done a npm install so the node module is is where it should be. Its worth pointing out its called gulp-browserify in the node-module.

As well as I've installed browserify globally on my mac.

Let me know your thoughts or if there is any information im missing.

I'm new to react and trying to literally just set up node.js as a backend and create a react environment.

Comment: Nice suggestion but that didn't do it.

Comment: Can you post your complete gulp file?

Comment: How do you installed that module?

Comment: [_"NOTE: THIS PLUGIN IS NO LONGER MAINTAINED"_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify)

Comment: Gerrit, I've updated the comment with everything i've got in my gulp file. I install the module by doing a npm install

Comment: God damn it.. I've been a plonker..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gulp-browserify` was [blacklisted by gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/issues/47)

You need to use `browserify` with `vinyl-source-stream`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source     = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    return browserify({ entries: ["./app/main.js"] })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/')));
});
```

Read more [here](https://viget.com/extend/gulp-browserify-starter-faq).

Comment: Why did gulp feel they needed to blacklist it?

Comment: Thanks for this comment but I'm still getting the same error after installing the npm and using your code. Any ideas?

Comment: I am working on a task similar to yours as we are speaking and I created this task and it works great right now. All I did was `npm install browserify --save`, `npm install vinyl-source-stream --save`. Make sure to `npm uninstall gulp-browserify --save`